# wp-admin pages return ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE

Tags: wp-admin, updates, options

update-core.php, update.php, and options-general.php no longer work.

index.php, profile.php, plugins.php, upload.php, etc all still seem to work

I have tried deactivating every plugin and reverting my theme to the default, but that didn't work.

I downloaded a fresh copy of 4.9.2, and used my current wp-config.php with it, but the pages still did not work.

I can activate and deactivate plugins, change the appearance of pages and content, but I cannot update or delete any plugins.

WP_DEBUG and WP_DEBUG_LOG didn't reveal anything.

What steps can I take to troubleshoot this? Is something in the SQL database corrupted?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/42345

After a lot of digging and following segfaults in strace and parsing out apache core dumps (and enlisting some outside help from a much more knowledgeable Linux guy) I dug this up on Wordpress's site.

The short answer to the problem is that there is an issue with PHP5 and libssh2 that was introduced in an update a few months ago. There is no actual fix for it, but it can be effectively worked around by installing this plugin: https://wordpress.org/plugins/ssh-sftp-updater-support/

It worked like a charm for me; all my users can log in normally and I can once again update plugins and WP Core through the GUI.

Hope this works for you, and others!

Comment: Installing that plugin fixes those pages. I still can't seem to update plugins or WP core though. I keep getting "could not copy file" errors. I've checked the permissions on all my files. The user and group and access bits seem correct...

Comment: That definitely sounds permission related. Assuming your permissions are properly configured (with chmod); have you checked the owner and group of the files/folder of your plugin directory?  I'm guessing the user is OK, based on your being able to install things by FTP (are the owning user and the FTP user the same?), but the group should at least contain the user that apache runs as, usually www-data and it should have read and write permissions to the folder.

Comment: This is mildly embarassing. It turns out the wp-content/ugprade folder had the wrong permissions.

`$ find -not -user wp-user -or -not -group www-data` was what I used to check for folders with the wrong permissions.